# Pointing to a directory in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to integrate a Wordpress blog page into my (php) website. So far I have been successful in creating an installing it into a subdirectory. I can see that this works.

The issue I am facing is that images are not showing (the alt text is). The issue is that Wordpress uses a incorrect path to the flies:

Wrong Path: `https://sitename.com/wordpress/blog/images/brand/logo.png`
Correct: `https://sitename.com/images/brand/logo.png`

It should not have `/wordpress/blog/`in it.

How do I go about resolving this to point at the correct directory without duplicating the files. Note that in the code the path is is written as: `/images/brand/logo.png`

Comment: Can you post some code for these images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your image folder lays inside theme directory, then you can use

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/brand/logo.png" />
```

If your image folder lays outside the theme directory, then you may use

```
<img src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/images/brand/logo.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your htaccess in your root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wordpress/blog/images/(.*)$ /images/$1 [L]
```

That should rewrite those urls.

Depending on your needs, you may also want to consider this [article](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-get-rid-of-wordpress-from-your-wordpress-site-url/). It doesn't sound like your problem is that you want to change all urls, only the urls to your images.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have path as /images/brand/logo.png , just go 2 levels up like this;

../../images/brand/logo.png

If you are using a wordpress default theme/img upload folder then wordpress build in function get_stylesheet_directory() would work for you. In this case no matter where you shift your project it will always grab this path, this much better then hardcoding path every time.